# Save and load from file at a selected line?

Tags: c#

I wonder if it's possible to save and load data in a simple textfile at/from a selected line, just like an ArrayList?

Comment: are the lines all the same length?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  But you'll have to write your own library to do it.  However, if your library isn't tailored to a specific subset of all possible text files, your library will most likely have poor performance.  I expect performance is the reason why such functionality isn't part of the BCL.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Read the contents of a file starting somewhere other than the beginning? What does this have to do with an ArrayList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your lines are all the same number of bytes (not just characters) this isn't possible in general without reading the whole file before the line in question when reading, or rewriting the remainder of the file when writing. You can't just insert or delete bytes from the middle of a file.

If you're using .NET 4 you can get at the nth line in a file pretty easily:

```
string line = File.ReadLines("file.txt").ElementAt(lineNumber);
```

Be aware that that will need to read all the preceding text though.

*Replacing* a line is trickier - the *simplest* way (if it's a small enough file to fit into memory) is to read the whole file into an array of lines, change a line, then write the whole thing out again:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
lines[lineNumber] = replacementLine;
File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", lines);
```

There are more efficient ways of doing this, but they'd be considerably more complicated.

Comment: works for small files but for larger files? Yeah, lots of way to do this.  @3D-Kreativ, Java has an efficient way of doing this with Random Access Files but C# you have to know the number of bytes of each line to seek to the line number you need if you want to try with Random Access Files.

Comment: @Subs: This isn't a difference between Java and C# (or Java and .NET). C# supports random access too - but on *both* platforms you need to know the position to seek to. How would you expect Java to do this better?

Comment: @Subs: You'd still need to know where to seek. If you know where to seek to, you can seek there in .NET on a `FileStream`, then create a `StreamReader` wrapping it and read a line from that. I still don't see how you think this helps. Note that `RandomAccessFile` doesn't even allow the encoding to be specified, making it even less useful, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I stand by Skeet’s answer to this question for the majority of scenarios.

For specific cases where the performance requirement justifies the extra programming effort involved, you could use an approach similar to databases: Maintain an index structure that specifies the offset for each line in your file. This index would only need to be created once in the beginning, and then updated in-memory following any file modification. It may be persisted to disk for subsequent runs of your application.

Here is some sample code for initializing the index (not tested to run):

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("source.txt");
var newlineIndexes = bytes.Select((byteValue, index) => new { byteValue, index })
                          .Where(p => p.byteValue == '\n' && 
                                      p.index < bytes.Length - 1)
                          .Select(p => p.index + 1);
var lineIndexes = (new int[] { 0 }).Concat(newlineIndexes).ToList();
```